# How to remove the padding around ion-item?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to remove `padding` from my ion-item so that it can occupy the full `width` of the page.

Please look in the dev tools to see the `padding` around the ion-item.

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail>
        <img class="imgmg" src="...">
      </ion-thumbnail> 
      <h2>Text</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The ion-item has a padding of 16px, when I inspect the ion-item and also on the class="scroll-content" there I found scss in the inspector with

```
ion-app.md [padding] .scroll-content {
    padding: 16px;
}
```

If I remove this padding then ion-item can occupy the whole width by removing this padding, but When I use this in my scss file the padding is not removed.

Comment: try to add an `id = 'ion-overrides'` or whatever you want to call it to your body element and then in your scss change the `ion-app.md [padding] .scroll-content {...}`  to `#ion-overrides ion-app.md [padding] .scroll-content {...}`. You might need to specify the element in more detail because the css for the ion elements get added after yours and so it overrides your css.

Comment: but how can I add the id to ion-app .md ?

Comment: @Aditya i solve your problem please check it

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can solve `ion-item` padding different way...

**First: Using ion-no-padding class**

```
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding">
  <ion-thumbnail>
    <img class="imgmg" src="...">
  </ion-thumbnail> 
  <h2>Text</h2>
</ion-item>
```

**Second: Using css or inline style**

```
<ion-item style="padding:0px !important;">
  <ion-thumbnail>
    <img class="imgmg" src="...">
  </ion-thumbnail> 
  <h2>Text</h2>
</ion-item>
```

**Edit** : As Ionic 5.X we must use CSS utilities by class instead of attributes ( [ionic/BREAKING.md](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/BREAKING.md#css-utilities) ).

Comment: Method 1 works for most of the padding.  But it doesn't seem to override the logical css, so I am left with some calculated padding attached to the padding-inline-end property under the item-inner class.  Has anyone found a solution to this?  `padding-inline-end: calc(var(--ion-safe-area-right, 0px) + var(--inner-padding-end));`

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties It has all the properties and css4 variables.

Comment: For Ionic 5.X, what do I do if I wish to use `margin` and `text-right`, I can only have one class.

Comment: @BanAnanas can you add more than one class? If someone is not forbidding you to use more than one class, you can add multible classes separating them with ` ` (space), i.e. `class="class1 class2 classN"`

Answer (score 72):

For those who are using ionic 4, you should use [Ionic CSS Utilties for padding](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#element-padding)

In short, you have to code this:

```
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding">
  <ion-thumbnail>
    <img class="imgmg" src="...">
  </ion-thumbnail> 
  <h2>Text</h2>
</ion-item>
```

If you want to remove inner paddding, use ion-item [custom CSS properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties):

```
ion-item {
  --padding-end: 0px;
  --inner-padding-end: 0px;
  // here other custom CSS from documentation
}
```

Comment: One issue that I had is that I was putting these on an inner (child) element and these need to go on the ion-item (parent) element. For this to work.  

Facepalm!

Answer (score 11):

I had to use custom [CSS properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables) for [ion-item](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item)

```
ion-item {
  --inner-padding-bottom: 0;
  --inner-padding-end: 0;
  --inner-padding-start: 0;
  --inner-padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just give `ion-no-padding` class to `ion-item` and it will remove the padding:

```
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding">
  <h2>Text</h2>
</ion-item>
```

[Refer to the ionic docs.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/)

Comment: I am upvoting your answer because I got idea from your answer.

Comment: This will not remove padding from item-inner

Answer (score 5):

Also had the same maddening problem. It turns out that ion-item has a few --inner-padding rules that need to be overridden to stop padding appearing on it's children

[image]

As well as adding the

```
class="ion-no-padding"
```

I also needed to add the following css style rule

```
--inner-padding-end: 0 !important;
```

Making the final element

```
<ion-item *virtualItem="let section" lines="none" class="ion-no-padding" style="--inner-padding-end: 0 !important;">
...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer not to add no-padding to every ion-item, and remove it for the whole app.

For **ionic v4**, you can add this to global.scss:

```
ion-item {
    --padding-start: 0;
}
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties

Answer (score -2):

Removing padding from the content of the page solves the problem

```
<ion-content> 
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail>
        <img class="imgmg" src="...">
      </ion-thumbnail> 
      <h2>Text</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer solves the initial problem, and also add some example if needed.